# Trouble loading lots of images from web

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make a simple instagram feed display with WPF. I have a ListView which is bound to an ObservableCollection of image url's retrieved from the Instagram API. For some reason, I can only load the first 10 or so (even though I am trying to bind more). If I try to load lower resolution images, then it seems to work ok. But I'm not talking about massive images anyway (maybe around 100k each).

Here is some example code with a list of hard coded images from instagram. For me, this only loads the first 10, then misses number 11, then loads number 12. I have no idea why.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="List" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="250" Height="250" Background="Orange">
                <Image Margin="3" Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
List<string> content = new List<string>()
{
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23498621_155088151891201_5838888733310451712_n.jpg",      
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/23421369_1935881716650536_2751759012239245312_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23498900_2424691114423634_1760461413358239744_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23498900_2424691114423634_1760461413358239744_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23347618_263128534210376_920911369891479552_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23421069_1500830839998934_8413516091602501632_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23417348_742804169243503_6556496499100876800_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23347902_2017564028488677_2880579113104441344_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23421331_334537296949861_4296430067371737088_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23421331_334537296949861_4296430067371737088_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23416590_1928818560779337_7080637368553701376_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/23421758_491705774540588_6178820534202007552_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23421099_1728264697245367_6448825186568372224_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23416994_133163334113394_1499431022142423040_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23421239_1483718185060885_8134914164545028096_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23280089_1942832749376286_3936575794389712896_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23347674_2006888666245374_7306582919252803584_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23347388_119626992143009_7585283007787827200_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23421865_900301160123071_1326331715420946432_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23421253_148762415872849_1558483017121398784_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/23507217_1953269574998281_6711372701967056896_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/23507217_1953269574998281_6711372701967056896_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23498098_2009691429314434_8349013357923139584_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/23347679_315062128974030_5091325576380153856_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/23421083_1777350415899180_3004366087824343040_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/23421083_1777350415899180_3004366087824343040_n.jpg",
    "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23498903_773821689486761_9202713497564086272_n.jpg"
};

List.ItemsSource = content;
```

Comment: Seems that the ObservableCollection is entirely redundant. You could as well write `List.ItemsSource = content;` If for whatever reason you still need it, initialize it like `oDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(content);`

Comment: Yes you're right, that was left over from the binding which I'm not showing in the example code. Edited the code now to remove the observable collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into the maximum connection limit to the same host for your application.

In your app.config file, you can add the following underneath configuration:

```
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="1000" />
  </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/connectionmanagement-element-network-settings). Obviously you should tailor your entry to what your application actually needs.